# best place to persist an nsmutablearray of objects

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I'm an OSX beginner. Where is the best place to store an `NSMutableArray` of objects.  the objects need to be presented to the user for updating, deleting etc. I've already written the code to manage and present the data to the user. i just need to now start saving the data. i don't envisage the array containing more than 50 objects.

i'm not sure where to persist the data. should i use a os file or `NSUserDefaults`.  what does osx etiquette say?

thanks

Comment: Depends on usage. Depends how much data there is.   Depends how often the data is modified.  Depends how the data is loaded.  Depends if the data is searchable.

Comment: @stupot It means that someone has downvoted your question.  A pointless thing to do, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention that the user will need to update and delete the data, Core Data is a very good option.

> In addition to the benefits of the framework itself, Core Data integrates well with the OS X tool chain. The model design tools allow you to create your schema graphically, quickly and easily. You can use templates in the Instruments application to measure Core Data’s performance, and to debug various problems. On OS X desktop, Core Data also integrates with Interface Builder to allow you to create user interfaces from your model. These aspects help to further shorten your application design, implementation, and debugging cycles.

You can read more about the key features [in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTechnologyOverview.html) to be sure that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for that. I took a look at Core Data but decided that for my app NSUserDefaults would suffice. My app uses a very simple data model with a lot of derived data. I think my main concern was whether I should be using NSUD for app data as well as user preferences.

Comment: Ok. To your last point, NSUD will work -- but just because it does/can doesn't mean it's the best solution. It doesn't mean Core Data is either, but this is just something to think about if your data model changes or expands in the future.